# Coefficients of Fourier series of function defined on $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The Fourier series (complex form) for continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $[-l, l]$ is
$$ \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} c_{k} e^{ik \pi x/l} $$

where
$$ c_{k} = \frac{1}{2l} \int_{-1}^{l} f(x) e^{-ik\pi x/l}dx $$

---

Now if I have a continuous function $g(x)$ defined on $[0, 2\pi]$, then I can **shift** the function to the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ by defining a new function
$$ f(x) = g(x+\pi), \:\: x \in [-\pi, \pi]$$

So in terms of Fourier series, the coefficient $c_{k}$ is therefore

$$ c_{k} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-ik\pi x/\pi} dx  $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(x+\pi) e^{-ik\pi x/\pi} dx $$

Now let $y = x+\pi$, then the above is

$$ c_{k} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} g(y) e^{-ik\pi (y-\pi)/\pi} dy $$

or
$$ c_{k} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} g(y) e^{-iky} e^{i k \pi} dy $$

So we have that

$$ c_{k} = \begin{cases}  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} g(y) e^{-iky}dy, \:\:\:\: k \:\: \text{ even}   \\
- \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} g(y) e^{-iky}  dy, \:\:\:\: k \:\: \text{ odd} \end{cases} $$

---

***Problem***

But according to a paper here: https://researchspace.ukzn.ac.za/bitstream/handle/10413/11809/Sibandze_Dan_Behlule_2013.pdf;sequence=1  (see page 4 equation $1.1$) ....

.... the coefficient $c_{k}$ for a function $g(x)$ defined on $[0,2\pi]$ is computed as

$$  c_{k} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} g(x) e^{-ikx}dx,    $$

do I miss something here?

Comment: they are using a different way to go between the two intervals: they are using the  periodic extension

Comment: @CalvinKhor what do you mean? could you elaborate in answer..?

Comment: Instead of doing a shift, you just define a function on $\mathbb R$ by saying $f(x+k2\pi):=f(x)$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z$. In particular it is a function on $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor ok thanks. I think you meant: $c_{k} = \frac{1}{4 \pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-ikx} dx = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \left( 2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-ikx} dx \right) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \left(  \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-ikx} dx \right)$